# How to parameterized load testing in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing

We are doing load testing/ web performance test where we need to parameterized the authentication values.

We need to parameterize the test from the point after which authentication is done and we will receive an auth token.

Any help on this appreciated !